# Is there a way to easily open/edit the files shown in the PHP errors in your browser?

Tags: php

Is there a way (through a browser addon or other means) to easily open the files shown to be causing errors?

For example, it would be nifty to be able to click on the Notice below and open the file in my IDE, rather than having to go back to my IDE and look for the file when the notice appears.

**Notice: Undefined index: xyz in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 141**

Comment: learn to love debugging and stop being so lazy...:P

Comment: a file name and line number are not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research I have found that installing Xdebug and making use of the **file_link_format** configuration variable was exactly what I needed.

[This forum thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic20597.html) helped me to get it set up with Netbeans which is the IDE I am using but you will be able to get it to work with any IDE/text editor with a change to the batch file they suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do something using [`set_error_handler`](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler) and [`register_shutdown_function`](http://ca.php.net/register_shutdown_function) (to handle fatal errors) to intercept the errors and display them differently. The example below isn't a *fully functional* of what you're asking but should point you in the right direction. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to launch the program of your choice.

```
<?php

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
  echo $errstr . ' in <a href="file://' . $errfile . '">'.$errfile.'</a> on line ' . $errline . PHP_EOL;
}

function shutdown_handler()
{
  $err = error_get_last();
  
  // Fatal errors don't trigger the error handler so trigger the error handler manually.
  if ( ! empty($err['type']) && $err['type'] === E_ERROR )
    error_handler($err['type'], $err['message'], $err['file'], $err['line']);
}

set_error_handler('error_handler');
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_handler');

// The following 2 line throw errors.
preg_replace('invalid regex', '', 'Sample');
stack('overflow');
```